# Echoing Fetch_Assoc Fails

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, echo

I'm really stuck on something here, I honestly cannot see anything wrong here myself and I've done something like this several times throughout my site.

I want my home page to update with up to the three most recent news updates. I have my table all setup with an entry for testing as well. This is my php code to display the three most recent posts:

```
    <?php
$sql = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY PostCreated ASC LIMIT 3");

if($sql)
    {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql))
            {
                echo $row['PostContent'];
            }
        else
            {
                echo "Cannot fetch current news update. Error: " . mysqli_error($link);
            }
    }
else
    {
        echo "Cannot fetch current news update. Error: " . mysqli_error($link);
    }
?>
```

So as you can see it grabs the three most recents and I have proved this by placing `echo mysqli_num_rows($sql);` just before the `while loop`. This returns `1` which is correct as there is only one entry.

The problem comes when I am attempting to `echo $row['PostContent'];` The entire page goes blank, if I take the while loop out of the equation, it will display the rest of the page, but it is almost as if me using `echo $row['PostContent'];` stops the rest of the page loading at all?

Any help would be appreciated, and I am so sorry if this is a really silly mistake on my part that ends up wasting your time guys. Thank you!

Comment: Why are you using `else` after `while`?

Comment: Isn't that supposed to be `echo .$row['PostContent'];`? I think you forgot the `dot`. Could it be? I'm just starting to learn SQL and have noticed stuff like that throughout my tutorials.

Comment: @Fred `.`? why is that?

Comment: @kevin To be honest with you Kevin, I can't tell you the `why`. I can only say that I've noticed stuff like that in my tutorials, I just began yesterday actually, and have noticed a dot when echoing rows. For example `echo $row['Position']. " - ". $row['Meal'];`. Then again, I could be wrong.

Comment: @kevin I am pretty sure I have no idea, I'll remove that, I think this WAS an if statement previously, as it only displayed one news item.

Comment: @kevin Do you want to add that as an answer Kevin? That actually solved this! I feel so stupid!

Comment: posted :)  @Fred dude, I can't believe you are still learning SQL. I've talked to u as 'Kevin Paladin' before and I know you are a genius in web-development :)

Comment: Yep, I was wrong lol - well I'm glad this worked out for you Mike. Good call Kevin, cheers all.

Comment: @kevin Yeah, I know hahaha. This is stuff I should've learned a long time ago. Believe it or not, I started off in Databases back in the mid 90s, using dBASE IV; look it up! lol I took a right turn in graphic arts back then, so never kept up with the tech stuff, but I'm headed there. I'm a web designer with pretty good skills in certain domains, but SQL is not one of them right now. I am good however at noticing `patterns`. **The 90s you say?** Yes, I'm that old! Gawd, I'm pushing 50 here lads!

Comment: @Fred BTW, `.` is used to concatenate two strings.

Comment: @kevin Yes I knew that, but I thought they were used for something else in SQL. I did say *Then again, I could be wrong* lol

Comment: **+1** - I found it useful in my learning of SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probable problems here are:

1. You have used an `else` block after the `while` loop.
2. You have `error_reporting` turned off.

These explain the page going blank when `while` is present and the page executing the rest when it is taken away.

Comment: I'm going to `+1` this, as I found it useful in my learning SQL. Cheers Kevin.

Comment: @Fred http://stackoverflow.com/users/1662984/kevin I wud like to add u to my contacts

Comment: Sure that'd be good, how do we do that? Is that something that can be done on SO? I haven't seen the option for it.

Comment: Email has been sent Kevin. Check your Spam just in case.

Answer (score 1):

Here is your problem.

```
else
            {
                echo "Cannot fetch current news update. Error: " . mysqli_error($link);
            }
```

Cannot use this after while loop.

Comment: @Fred That really shouldn't stop anyone from trying to add additional content.  Of course, this does seem to be a redundant part of the accepted answer...

Comment: @ebyrob True. Just as long as they are "correct" answers ;-) Cheers